# ESP8266 Node MCU powered by battery

Tags: esp8266, battery, nodemcu

I am new to ESP8266 and started just building basic devices using it. However I am using USB 5V wall adapter as nodeMCU has USB UART converter to 3.3V.

If I want to make it battery powered what is simple , small ( in volume so that it can fit along with nodemcu and sensors in a small case) and economical approach that keeps my nodemcu still safe? 
-One option I can think of is to connect a Li-ion battery of 3.7V to VIN.
-Another one is to use bigger voltage and use a converter to convert it down to around 5V and then use that to connect to VIN.

Please let me know if this works ? else if there is any better option please do suggest. Also if you are referring to any items/products please help give the exact model numbers so that I can search on internet to consider buying them.

Lastly I am not much aware of electric circuits  & terminology yet ( learning them), so please help explain me in basic terms possible.

Ps: this question was seen on stackoverflow some times but I couldnt find one single consolidated answer and am confused by it. Appreciate your understanding.

Thanks,
Sridhar.

Comment: You might want to ask this in the electronics sister site since this is about hardware, not programming

Comment: use an LDO like the ams117@3.3, or something even better, and feed the output to VCC instead of VIN. you might dip below 3.3v on a low batt, but the ESP can handle down to 2.9v or so. a DC-DC boost+buck converter can output 3.3v from any input voltage, and will result in longer battery life (+33%) than a linear regulator would provide.

Comment: [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 2):

This really would be better suited for the electronics sister site or [a esp8266.com forum](http://www.esp8266.com/viewforum.php?f=17) but for what it's wort here's my input.

IMHO the most convenient option you have is to buy a devkit with a LiPo connector. I recommend a [WeMOS D1 mini](https://frightanic.com/go/wemos-store/) plus a fitting [battery shield](https://frightanic.com/go/wemos-store/). An alternative is the [Adafruit Feather HUZZAH](https://www.adafruit.com/product/3404).

It can sometimes be a bit of a challenge to find the right connectors for those boards. Gotcha! different revisions of those boards might use different connectors. Currently the WeMOS battery shield uses a 2 pin JST PH 2.0mm.

Answer (score 0):

**No**, you cannot power a NodeMCU using a 3.7v li-ion battery ***directly***. A fully charged Li-ion battery outputs a voltage of **4.2v**. The NodeMCU board has a (**5v and above**) vin slot along with two **3.6v** slots. If you directly connect the battery to the 3.6v, it may ***fry*** the NodeMCU board. So typically, there are 3 ways you can connect the battery without frying your board in this scenario:

1. You can use a ***boost converter*** to convert the 4.2v output to 5v. Then connect it to vin. This will draw more current and battery discharges quickly (eg: MT3608 step up boost converter).
2. You can use a ***buck converter*** to convert the 4.2v to a steady 3.6v (eg: LM2596 step down converter).
3. Finally, the most efficient way is to connect a 3.3v ***LDO*** in middle. The difference between using a buck and LDO is, buck provides a constant and steady 3.6v output, where as LDO's output depends on the input voltage from battery (eg: S111733PI).